# Different CPU usage in Java VisualVM

Tags: java, performance, cpu, hardware, visualvm

In a game I'm making, I went to check why my FPS was throttling on my laptop in Java VisualVM. (I develop on my computer, which has better specs). What I noticed was that the function 'render()' in my Tiles class was hogging up most of my CPU time on my laptop. ([See this picture for laptop CPU times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h0Qc.png))

Next, I went to check if this was the case on my desktop as well, since there is no FPS throttle there. The results on my desktop were as follows: [(Desktop CPU times)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMgHx.png)

What struck me as odd, was that on my laptop, rendering the tiles seems to hog most of the CPU time, whereas on my desktop, the game loop itself takes up most CPU time.

I'm struggling to find an explanation for this. Could it be a hardware difference? And how is it that the render() method takes up more CPU time than the actual game loop (which it is a part of)?

**Laptop specs:**

CPU: Intel i7-7500U (4 core 2.70Ghz)

GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620 (Display) NVidia GeForce 940MX (Render)

RAM: 8GB

**Desktop specs:**

CPU: Intel i5-4460 (4 core 3.2Ghz)

GPU: NVidia GeForce GTX 760

RAM: 8GB

Comment: It really sounds like your desktop's JVM is effectively utilizing your GPU ... and your laptop's JVM isn't :(

Comment: Further to @paulsm4 's comment, are you sure that your laptop is using the NVidia for rendering? Perhaps it is doing everything in the slower Intel chip? Use a NVidia GPU usage monitor tool to see if it is being used or not. BTW, if it's not being used, I would suggest deleting this Q and posting a new one on how to turn on the NVidia GPU with whatever API you are using.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Is there a way to make JVM use my GPU?